# Closed set contains only limit points and interior points?

Tags: metric-spaces

If $X$ is a metric space and $A\subseteq X$ is a closed subset, are the elements of $A$ only limit and interior points? That is $A = int(A)\cup E(A)$, where $E$ is the set of limit points of A?

$x\in X$ is said to be a limit point of $A$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$, the neighbourhood $N_\varepsilon(x)$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

My guess it that its true, but I'll appreciate if someone gives a proof or a counter example

Comment: @markvs No, a point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if there is a sequence of points in $A\setminus \{x\}$ converging to $x$. Equivalently, every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $A$ *other than $x$*.

Comment: Hi @markvs, thank you for you answer. Can you be more specific on what do you mean by 'some kind of compactness'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not true. Consider, for instance, $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the usual Euclidean metric. Both the interior and the set of limit points of $\mathbb{Z}$ are empty.

I believe it would be correct to say that $A$ is the union of:

- The interior of $A$,
- The set of limit points of $A$, and
- The set of isolated points of $A$.

Since closed sets contain their limit points, it's clear that the above three sets are all contained in $A$. To show $A$ is a subset of their union, it suffices to show that if $x \in A$ but $x$ is not in the interior of $A$ nor a limit point of $A$, then $x$ is an isolated point of $A$.

Since $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, there exists a neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}$ of $x$ containing only finitely many points of $A$, call them $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Let $\epsilon' = \min_{i} d(x,a_i)>0$. Then $N_{\epsilon'}(x)$ contains no points of $A$ other than $x$ itself, and therefore $x$ is an isolated point of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. If $p$ is a point of *any* metric space $X$, then the closure of $\{p\}$ is $\{p\}$ itself. But $p$ is neither an interior point of $\{p\}$ nor a limit point.

Comment: Thank you José. What about if I change the hypothesis for $int(A)$ and $E$ to be non empty?
ps. I've seen plenty of your answers in this community and I've found them very helpful.

Comment: @Mangostino That also does not work. Consider $[0,1] \cup\{2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Its interior is nonempty but $2$ is neither in the interior nor a limit point. You need to include isolated points for your statement to hold. See my answer for more details.

Comment: It looks like you've extended too far.  If $p$ is isolated in $X$, then $p$ is interior.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That is not true. The interior is the largest *open* set contained in $A$. An isolated point is not contained within any open set contained in $A$.

Comment: @kccu If $p$ is isolated in $X$, then $\{p\} \subset X$ is open, hence...?

Comment: @kccu Since your response is delayed, I'll have to give the punchline to my comment.  You seem to be making the same mistake I was pointing out in the answer of overextending.  A point $p \in X$ is isolated in $Y\subseteq X$ if and only if $\{p\}$ is open in $Y$, so $p$ would be interior to $\{p\}$ in $Y$.  In particular, if $Y=X$, then $p$ is isolated in $X$ if and only if $p$ is an interior point of $\{p\}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring $\{p\}$ may be open in $Y$, but it is not necessarily open in the underlying metric space $X$. The interior of $Y$ is the union of all subsets of $Y$ that are open in $X$ (not in $Y$).

Comment: @kccu Yes, but if $Y=X$?  Did you simply stop reading before my last sentence?  [I invite you to re-read our comment thread so far, starting with mine.  Your comments have been a lot of non sequitur to someone talking about isolated points of $X$]

Comment: I see what you are saying now, I read your comments too quickly. But my answer and first comment still hold - the points that are isolated in $Y$ (but not in $X$) are *not* part of the interior of $Y$ nor the set of limit points of $Y$, even when those sets are non-empty.